# Upgrade Mac TeXnicle

Tags: texnicle

I upgraded TeXnicle to 2.2.8 on my Mac. Now, I have a problem with making a PDF. Only the first page of the PDF appears and other pages are gray and they disappear. I think that the new version 2.2.8 has some bugs but I don't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in 2.2.8 (and 2.2.7) which appears when running on 10.6.8. The problem is that both these versions of TeXnicle are compiled using the latest tools and SDKs from Apple, and it seems that breaks the viewing of PDFs in TeXnicle. A solution is being investigated.

To workaround, you can

a) fall back to 2.2.6
b) use an external PDF viewer
c) click the zoom in/zoom out buttons to get the PDF to redraw.